# Convert ssh-dss key to .pem?

Tags: ssh, sftp, openssh, public-key

how can I convert an openssh dsa public key to .pem format?

is it possible?

I've used command

```
  openssl dsa -in u015_test.pub -outform pem > u015_test.pem
```

but this is the output:

```
  read DSA key
  unable to load Private Key
  23392:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
  unable to load Key
```

this is how my key appears:

```
 ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAMMjZ03z7hOuGYDaPmyBvuNS+LJmhYn1bWzWP8p+1/amuRPdHj68KnRDuaf8MJB3qBZ6xsu97vUjjuRDeEyFLVjsghK9TiKBsxv2Uv+fS4o0OJzP............
```

Answer (score 3):

To convert ssh keys, you should use `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -e -m PEM -f u015_test.pub
```

or if you want to use the key with openssl:

```
ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8 -f u015_test.pub
```

To try if it works, use:

```
ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8 -f u015_test.pub | openssl dsa -pubin
```

Comment: this is the output: "read DSA key
unable to load Key
11625:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:647:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
"

Comment: Could you pleas post what the key looks like? I'm not really sure what kind of key you have.

Comment: strange, I don't know why this doesn't work. Where do you get this error? When exporting, or when you try to use it with openssl?